# OpenCV high contrast edge smoothing with Aruco

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, aruco

I have this image of an Aruco marker:
[image]

I generally have been performing a noise cleanup and rotation using `cv.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored` resulting in:

[image]

I still have these jagged edges which I assume is from the camera sensor not quite having a single line of the pixel color. How do I process this to reduce the edge noise while still preserving enough detail to keep the marker edges sharp enough for a good calibration?

Edit:

Marker detected position:

```
7: [[2567.125732421875, 1694.821533203125],
    [2681.59130859375, 1697.886962890625],
    [2690.694091796875, 1740.62255859375],
    [2570.4765625, 1738.4224853515625]]
```

Source data 150x150px:

[image]

Comment: are these threads in white due to aliasing?  how many pixels do you have on each hump? what is the size of this image, pixel-wise?

Comment: Native res is 5000x4000. At this zoom level, 500% zoom. The white thread is an actual white edge from it being mounted on 1/4 in poster board. I added the real detected corner positions for size reference

Comment: aruco markers require "quiet zone", white border. -- [mre] required, i.e. true source data, untouched, not screenshots. describe the pipeline that generated these pictures. what debayering is applied?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Arcuo's don't **explicitly require** a white quiet zone, but it definitely would help with edge contrast. I added the unprocessed source data image. The debayering is done on the camera as I've set the data output to BGR8Packed. Camera: https://emergentvisiontec.com/products/hb-camera-series/hb-25000-sb/

Comment: For now, I've solved this by using `cv.demosaicing(rawimage, cv.COLOR_BayerRG2RGB_EA)` on the raw `BayerRG8` data.